# pandas groupby then aggregate results order not repeatable?

Tags: pandas, aggregate, python-3.5, pandas-groupby

Here's my codes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                   'v1': [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5],
                   'v2': [7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
                   'v3': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]})

df.groupby('id').agg({'v1': ['count', 'sum'],
                      'v2': 'mean',
                      'v3': 'sum'})
```

My issue is that every time I run this code (in jupyter notebook), the resulted dataframe have different column orders. Is this a bug in pandas?

My next step is to rename the resulted dataframe, but with no reproducible order, it is kinda impossible to write a reusable code to do that. How could I work around it?

Btw, I am using python 3.5 and pandas 0.23.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.7. Maybe switch to that?

Comment: I think adding `.sort_index(1)` should ensure your columns are always sorted in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get different ordering when I run the code multiple times. However, if you're running into this problem, you could just name the order you want after your `agg`. For instance, if you wanted the order `v2`, `v3`, `v1`, do:

```
df.groupby('id',sort=False).agg({'v1': ['count', 'sum'],
                      'v2': 'mean',
                      'v3': 'sum'})[['v2','v3','v1']]

     v2  v3    v1    
   mean sum count sum
id                   
a   6.5   6     2   3
b   4.0  24     3  12
```

Or if you simply want the same ordering as your original dataframe:

```
df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg({'v1': ['count', 'sum'],
                                     'v2': 'mean',
                                     'v3': 'sum'})[df.columns]

  id    v1       v2  v3
     count sum mean sum
0  a     2   3  6.5   6
1  b     3  12  4.0  24
```

but all in all, @Allolz's comment makes the most sense IMO, using `sort_index(1)`:

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'v1': ['count', 'sum'],
                      'v2': 'mean',
                      'v3': 'sum'}).sort_index(1)
```

Comment: I like the first method the best since I can fully control the order as I want. Thanks @sacul.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` keys are not ordered in Python 3.5; this applies to the `dict`s used in `pd.DataFrame()` and `.agg()` in your code.  You could used an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module in the Python standard library or you could use `DataFrame.reindex()` to re-organize your columns and rows as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'v1': [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5],
    'v2': [7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
    'v3': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
})

df = df.set_index('id')
df = df.reindex(columns=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'])

df.groupby(level='id').agg({
    'v1': ['count', 'sum'],
    'v2': 'mean',
    'v3': 'sum'
})
```

`DataFrame.reindex()` is more general than `DataFrame.sort_index()`.